# Form values not posting

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have two pages. The first one I am sending data over to the second page. The second page I am using to edit the data sent over and other data within my database. I call for the data I sent over like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
```

The issue is I have other data on the page that and whenever I edit any of this information, I want to be able to do an `UPDATE query` to save the new information. However, my query isn't working and I believe it is because my new input field's (data I didn't send over from the first page) data is not being recognized.

Whenever I var_dump the values, I get the data (and in the same format) as how I sent it over to this page.

Here is my code for the second page:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = $_POST['id'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$product = $_POST['product'];

$newId = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


try {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $name = '';
    $user = '';
    $password = '';

    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $password);

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

}

    $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$newId' ");
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //print_r($stmt);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    $productAmount = $row['amount'];
    $productAvailable = $row['available'];

?>

<form name="update" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $newId; ?>">
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>">
<input type="text" name="last" value="<?php echo $last; ?>">
<input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $product; ?>">
<input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="available" value="<?php echo $row['available']; ?>">

<button type="submit">Update Product Information</button>
</form>
<?php 
}
var_dump($_POST);


if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE users SET first = ?, last = ?, product = ?, amount = ?, available = ? WHERE id = ?");

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['first']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['last']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['product']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $productAmount);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $productAvailable);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $newId);

    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

When I do `var_dump($_POST);` I get the following values, clearly not including the `amount` and `available` data.

`array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["first"]=> string(3) "Tom" ["last"]=> string(5) "Brady" ["product"]=> string(3) "Tea" ["edit"]=> string(4) "Edit" }`

Why isn't all my data being recognized?

Comment: Change the button to `<input type="submit" value="Update Product Information" />`

Comment: Sigh. When will people finally stop this strange habit to place a form and its processing code into a single file? That does not make _any_ sense.

Comment: @arkascha I will be changing this to an ajax submission once I get it working.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Whenever I hit the submit button, the var_dump value changes and displays all of the correct and updated fields, but the inputs themselves do not? array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["first"]=> string(4) "Suzy" ["last"]=> string(1) "J" ["product"]=> string(5) "Shoes" ["amount"]=> string(2) "28" ["available"]=> string(3) "Yes" }

Comment: @Becky Have you tried looking in your developer tools and seeing if the Request body contains `amount` and `available` after you hit Submit?

Comment: You're setting your inputs with the query. Once you submit the update form those variables become available.

Comment: Since you've POST arrays inside the same page as your MySQL, you need to do this `if(!empty($_POST['id'])){ $id = $_POST['id']; }` while doing the same thing for the other ones beneath that. You're also using `value="<?php echo $newId; ?>"` - I suggest you use a ternary operator for all of those. That's the best advice I can offer.

Comment: How are my inputs within the query? I am confused regarding that?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['update'])) {` will never resolve `true` either. A form name isn't passed with the `$_POST` array. Update the `<button>` to `<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Product Information">`

Comment: Another thing `<form name="update"` and you're using `if(isset($_POST['update']))`. Conditional statements do not use `<form>` with name attributes. You need to name your `<button>` that. Edit: I see that @Marcus and I basically wrote the same thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What is a ternary operator? Also, where are you referring to put the `!empty` at? At the top with the variables?

Comment: Remember when I said your logic flow is flawed on the other post? This is what I am talking about. Clicking the update resets the POST array and the additional two variables will be available after the click in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Yes at the top, all 4 of them. Ternary examples `$var = !empty($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : '';` and `value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : ''; ?>"`

Comment: @JayBlanchard So, are you saying I should move my update query above my inputs or vise versa?

Comment: No, I am just saying that you're logic needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So, are you saying to delete my variables and put this in their place? `if(!empty($_POST['id'])){ $id = $_POST['id']; }
if(!empty($_POST['first'])){ $first = $_POST['first']; }
if(!empty($_POST['last'])){ $last = $_POST['last']; }
if(!empty($_POST['product'])){ $product = $_POST['product']; }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Was what I had correct for the top variables? I just don't really get why those would be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere in your script do you have:

```
$productAmount = $_POST['amount'];
$productAvailable = $_POST['available'];
```

Add those 2 lines just below: `$product = $_POST['product'];`

**UPDATED**

<strike>Is the form supposed to be populated by the database? Or the form itself? If by the database (initially), then you'll need to change all the $variables in the form to their corresponding field names from the table, ie. `$row['id']`, `$row['first']`, etc.</strike>

See below for update...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = $_POST['id'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$productAmount = $_POST['amount'];
$productAvailable = $_POST['available'];

$newId = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

try {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $name = '';
    $user = '';
    $password = '';

    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $password);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE users SET first = ?, last = ?, product = ?, amount = ?, available = ? WHERE id = ?");

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['first']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['last']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['product']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['amount']);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['available']);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $newId);

    $stmt->execute();
}

if ( !empty($newId) ) {
    $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$newId' ");
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $row['first']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="last" value="<?php echo $row['last']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $row['product']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="available" value="<?php echo $row['available']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Product Information">
        </form>
        <?php 
    }
}
var_dump($_POST);
```

For the *Undefined index* just use a ternary in your form like so:

```
... value="<?php echo !empty($row['amount']) ? $row['amount'] : ''; ?>">
... value="<?php echo !empty($row['amount']) ? $row['available'] : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: Those two lines are there. Read the post more carefully.

Comment: Do a find search on the page, @Marcus

Comment: I see `$row['amount']` and `$row['available']`, but not `$_POST['amount']` or `$_POST['available']`

Comment: Those rows come from a query the OP is running.

Comment: I understand that, but how does she expect to get those values from `$_POST` if she's not inflicting them into the query?

Comment: She puts them into a form which then gets submitted.

Comment: And then what happens with them? Think about it... they're not being inserted into the DB anywhere, right? How would you expect to retrieve those values from the form if you're not pulling them from the form?

Comment: Ah - I see what you're saying. Just as I told her in her previous post her logic is jacked up.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, the form is populated by the database.

Comment: Grab my latest updated code and try that (backup your current code first though).

Comment: @Marcus Moving the page up did it! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Please mark solved if you don't need any more help.

Comment: @Marcus I moved those variables down right under `if(isset($_POST['update'])) {` and it cleared that up. Would that be fine or to do it the way you did?

Comment: You have to follow the logic, ie. `if(isset($_POST['update'])) {` means "if the form has been submitted, then do something...". So, while I'm not entirely sure which variables you're speaking of, if you're speaking of any of the `$_POST` variables (`$_POST['amount']`, etc), then placing them within the `if(isset($_POST['update'])) {` makes sense. You're logic in the script is kinda wish-washy though. You need to take some time and think things through using Layman's terms whenever possible, ie. "if this, else that, do something" and so on.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. What part of my logic in this doesn't make sense?

Comment: In the beginning, having the form populate before updating the database was a prime example of poor logic. But it's OK.. you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
$stmt->bindParam(4, $productAmount);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $productAvailable);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['amount']);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['available']);
```

So the result of cleaning up second part of your code would be this:

- No need for a form name.
- `name="update"` goes in the button's markup.
- `$_POST` array now contains the new variables.
- We check to make sure update is set before running the query.

---

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $newId; ?>">
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>">
<input type="text" name="last" value="<?php echo $last; ?>">
<input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $product; ?>">
<input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="available" value="<?php echo $row['available']; ?>">

<button type="submit" name="update">Update Product Information</button>

</form>
<?php 
}


if(isset($_POST['update'])) { // checking the button
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE users SET first = ?, last = ?, product = ?, amount = ?, available = ? WHERE id = ?");

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['first']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['last']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['product']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['amount']); // now it is in the POST array
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['available']); // same here
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $newId);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: I had my new inputs like that in my last question and you said that having $_POST was messing it up because I didn't send those over from my other page? Anyways, I changed it and it works, but I have to enter the data in twice and hit update? `$stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['amount']);`

Comment: We're handling the POST for the second form. This data is being entered into that form automatically, you're not entering it. 1. You enter data into one form and submit. 2. That data is used to run a query and populate a second form, which is then submitted. I think you can probably trim this down some logically.

Comment: Any idea why I have to fill in the info twice to make it stay?

Comment: Which info are you filling in twice? Amount and availability should be coming from your query and setting the form values.

Comment: It seems to be for the `amount` and `available` inputs. If I fill it in and hit update, it does nothing. Then if I fill in something else and hit update, the first submission shows up. It is like it lags behind one submission.

Comment: You need to solve the problem related to the query getting the values. Check your error logs to see why `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$newId'` isn't working.

Comment: @Becky - that'd be because your `UPDATE` query is following the form population. Move it above the `SELECT` query (I've made an edit to my original answer showing what I mean). So you're updating the values (via the form), but the form is being populated prior to the updates actually being made resulting in you seeing *old* values, so-to-speak.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help regarding this. Sorry for the newb questions.